# Excel VBA type mismatch (error 13) for sheetname reference from a range on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have `Personal.xls` VBA code/macros that are designed to reformat any file of a certain structure that the code is run on. One of the tasks is to create a series of filtered tab sheets from a primary data sheet provided in the original file. I then create a new worksheet that creates checkboxes adjacent to a sheetname reference list.

I want to hide or unhide checked the underlying sheets for checked boxes. I created a button that automatically will run a macro when pressed (after checkboxes have been selected) that loops through the sheetnames and sets them visible or not. Being that I'm such a dummy...

I cannot get past syntax for objects and get the loop to perform without an error 13 type mismatch error. Here is the code I'm running and an attached picture of the active sheet that the code is referencing.

NB: D is the column where I'm storing the linked cell data for range A1 to "the number of sheets in the workbook".

```
Public Sub Button_Click()
 Dim I As Integer
 For I = 1 To Sheets.Count
 If Range("AZ" & I).Value = False Or Range("AZ" & I) = Empty Then
 Sheets(Range("A" & I)).Visible = False
 Else:
 Sheets(Range("A" & I)).Visible = True
 End If
 Next
 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You want to read [mcve]; and you want to edit your question so that it is human. Focus on your question, instead of complaining 5 times that you dont know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Sub Button_Click()
 Dim I As Integer
 Dim SheetName as String

 For I = 1 To Sheets.Count
 SheetName = Range("A" & I).Value
 If Range("AZ" & I).Value = False Or Range("AZ" & I) = Empty Then
 Sheets(SheetName).Visible = False
 Else:
 Sheets(SheetName).Visible = True
 End If
 Next
 End Sub
```

I think the type mismatch is coming from the Sheets(Range("A" & I)).Visible line. The Sheets object requires a string that contains the name of a valid sheet in the workbook. In your case, you are pointing to a range value, not a string. Since the Range value you pointed to contains the name of the sheet, I simply made the SheetName variable for the Sheets object to point to. Since SheetName is a string, it should not throw any 'type mismatch' errors. I hope this helps.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could provide some explanation of your solution and how/why it is resolving the question.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and its throwing a Runtime error 1004 Method 'Range" of object'_Global failed

Comment: Sorry...the error occurs in line...SheetName = Range("A" & I).Value

Comment: Could the fact that the code modules/macros are stored and run from personal.xlsx on another workbook's raw data?

Comment: I apologize...I put the "SheetName = " statement outside the For Next loop.  Now it just throws an error 9 subscript out of range.  But only after I select a certain combination of checkboxes.  Weird